# Is it cloaking to use e.preventdefault on the link to the second page to make users register before continuing?

Tags: seo, javascript, negative-seo

We have a very voluminous site. We want to index around 50,000 pages.

We want the pages to be all in the Google index and accessible.

We also want that if a user arrives on the first page, when he tries to click on the link of the second page in our pagination (footer of the first page), that it can access it only if it s' registered. However, it can access the second page without being registered via Google search results or type the URL into the bar.

With this in mind, I added an `e.preventDefault()` on the link to the second page.

I do not doubt the ability of Google to follow this link, nevertheless that asks me the question about the penalties, could Google consider this as an attempt at cloaking?

Personally I would say no, but I'm not 100% sure, thanks for your opinions on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with more research that is considered like "First Click free", this is a "white cloaking" for Google. As long as the user from Google can read the content he ask for (when he click in the link from google), this is ok !

Source Google : [First Click Free](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40543?hl=en)

Comment: I agree with this.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be an attempt at cloaking as you are showing the crawler something different to the user. Having said that Google has the ability to evaluate JavaScript on pages or links a index/crawl based on what the JavaScript does.

Comment: I don't understand, Google specify that cloacking is when you deserve different content to users. But hear it's not the case no ? the content is the same for all ! If google have in is index my url, but this url is not in any <a href> in my website, Google keep that url in his index (because google want content to deserve), why he can't index too this url ? It's no sence, because i can deserve all my content to Google, and after this done, delete all the links for this content and this will work, we going to stay in the index and no risk of cloaking, no ?